# Does Proverbs teach that all pride is evil? (Prov. 16:18–19)

Tags: hebrew

The following verses seem to indicate that all pride is evil:

```
  18Pride goes before ruin, 
  Arrogance, before failure. 
  19Better to be humble and among the lowly 
  Than to share spoils with the proud. 
        (Prov. 16:18–19, JPS Torah)
```

Does Proverbs teach that pride in general is always bad?

Comment: Hi Perry, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! This site has quite a specific format and is designed for specific types of questions arising from biblical texts, rather than general biblical topics. Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us, and take a look around some of the other questions for examples. I've Closed this question for now as it's off-topic.

Comment: You could ask this question related to a specific verse.

Comment: Since you tagged Hebrew, this passage in Proverbs may be what you have in mind.

Comment: @PerryWebb - I've refined the question further to focus on the text, asking what Proverbs teaching, rather than attempting some sort of wider systematic theology question which would be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Proverbs 16:18

> **Pride** [H1347] goes before destruction, a haughty spirit before a fall.

Exodus 15:7

> In the greatness of your **majesty** [H1347] you threw down those who opposed you. You unleashed your burning anger; it consumed them like stubble.

The word pride (H1347) has a good sense and a bad sense.

Brown-Driver-Briggs

> 1 exaltation, majesty, excellence,
> a. of nations, their wealth, power, magnificence of buildings ...
> b. of God ...
> c. majesty of Jordan, referring to the green and shady banks, clothed with willows, tamarisks, ...
> 2 pride (bad sense)

In Prov. 16:18–19, it is used negatively referring to human pride of the wicked. In the proverbs, it is used frequently negatively.

> Proverbs 8:13 To fear the LORD is to hate evil; I hate arrogant **pride**, evil conduct, and perverse speech.

> Proverbs 11:2
> When **pride** comes, disgrace follows, but with humility comes wisdom.

> Proverbs 18:12
> Before his downfall a man's heart is **proud**, but humility comes before honor.

> Proverbs 29:23
> A man's **pride** will bring him low, but a humble spirit will obtain honor.

Answer (score 0):

Proverbs is a warning rather than command. Pride translates:

> †גָּאוֹן ... exaltation... — 1. exaltation, majesty, excellence, ...  2. pride (bad sense)...
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 144). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Arrogance translates גֹּ֣בַהּ רֽוּחַ׃, a haughty spirit, the opposite of "poor in spirit."

Closely related is boasting.  Jer. 9:23-24 addresses this.

> Thus says the LORD: “Let not the wise man boast in his wisdom, let not the mighty man boast in his might, let not the rich man boast in his riches, 24 but let him who boasts boast in this, that he understands and knows me, that I am the LORD who practices steadfast love, justice, and righteousness in the earth. For in these things I delight, declares the LORD.”
> (Jer. 9:23–24, ESV)

Paul referenced this passage, especially in the Corinthian letters.

> And because of him you are in Christ Jesus, who became to us wisdom from God, righteousness and sanctification and redemption, 31 so that, as it is written, “Let the one who boasts, boast in the Lord.”
> (1 Cor. 1:30–31, ESV)

Pride is a problem when we credit to ourselves what we should thank God for.  Note how it caused divisions in the church at Corinth.

> I appeal to you, brothers, by the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that all of you agree, and that there be no divisions among you, but that you be united in the same mind and the same judgment. 11 For it has been reported to me by Chloe’s people that there is quarreling among you, my brothers. 12 What I mean is that each one of you says, “I follow Paul,” or “I follow Apollos,” or “I follow Cephas,” or “I follow Christ.” 13 Is Christ divided? Was Paul crucified for you? Or were you baptized in the name of Paul?
> (1 Cor. 1:10–13, ESV)

Also Jesus addressed self-righteous.  The Pharisee thanked God for his righteousness, but neglected praying about his sins as did the tax collector.  Pride can cause us to fail to acknowledge sin.

> He also told this parable to some who trusted in themselves that they were righteous, and treated others with contempt: 10 “Two men went up into the temple to pray, one a Pharisee and the other a tax collector. 11 The Pharisee, standing by himself, prayed thus: ‘God, I thank you that I am not like other men, extortioners, unjust, adulterers, or even like this tax collector. 12 I fast twice a week; I give tithes of all that I get.’ 13 But the tax collector, standing far off, would not even lift up his eyes to heaven, but beat his breast, saying, ‘God, be merciful to me, a sinner!’ 14 I tell you, this man went down to his house justified, rather than the other. For everyone who exalts himself will be humbled, but the one who humbles himself will be exalted.”
> (Luke 18:9–14, ESV)

Phil. 2 shows Christs example of putting others above himself.  Thus, pride can get in the way of loving others like Christ loved us.

> Do nothing from selfish ambition or conceit, but in humility count others more significant than yourselves. 4 Let each of you look not only to his own interests, but also to the interests of others. 5 Have this mind among yourselves, which is yours in Christ Jesus, 6 who, though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with God a thing to be grasped, 7 but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant,
> (Phil. 2:3–7, ESV)

Confidence can be a good form of pride:

> Such is the confidence that we have through Christ toward God. 5 Not that we are sufficient in ourselves to claim anything as coming from us, but our sufficiency is from God, 6 who has made us sufficient to be ministers of a new covenant, not of the letter but of the Spirit. For the letter kills, but the Spirit gives life.
> (2 Cor. 3:4–6, ESV)

David's confidence seems unreal to most of us. (Most of us would be like the scared soldiers.)

> And Saul said to David, “You are not able to go against this Philistine to fight with him, for you are but a youth, and he has been a man of war from his youth.” 34 But David said to Saul, “Your servant used to keep sheep for his father. And when there came a lion, or a bear, and took a lamb from the flock, 35 I went after him and struck him and delivered it out of his mouth. And if he arose against me, I caught him by his beard and struck him and killed him. 36 Your servant has struck down both lions and bears, and this uncircumcised Philistine shall be like one of them, for he has defied the armies of the living God.” 37 And David said, “The LORD who delivered me from the paw of the lion and from the paw of the bear will deliver me from the hand of this Philistine.” And Saul said to David, “Go, and the LORD be with you!”
> (1 Sam. 17:33–37, ESV)

Boldness for the truth can be a good kind of pride.

> And now, Lord, look upon their threats and grant to your servants to continue to speak your word with all boldness,
> (Acts 4:29, ESV)

This is how we should take pride in what we do:

> And whatever you do, in word or deed, do everything in the name of the Lord Jesus, giving thanks to God the Father through him.
> (Col. 3:17, ESV)

However, pride in making a living isn't good when we fail to recognize everything is from God. That's the meaning of "pride of life."

> For all that is in the world—the desires of the flesh and the desires of the eyes and pride of life—is not from the Father but is from the world.
> (1 John 2:16, ESV)

Look at the Apostle Peter.  (I will avoid quoting so many passages.)  Although  Peter had been called (John 1:42), he was still fishing.  Then, a Rabbi who was a carpenter, not a fisherman, told them where to catch more fish than they ever dreamed of, shattered their pride of life, and made them fishers of men (Luke 5:1-11).  However, Peter's confidence was shattered after denying Christ, so he went fishing, Jesus repeated the miracle, called Peter again, and gave Peter his confidence back (John 21).